# How to load js file on ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use [Firebase.getAsArray](https://github.com/katowulf/Firebase.getAsArray),
I include it on my index.html:

```
     <script src="lib/firebase.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/firebase-as-array.min.js"></script>
     <!-- AngularFire -->
     <script src="lib/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

when I am trying to use it I get

> ionic.bundle.js:26794 ReferenceError: getAsArray is not defined
>       at Object. (http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:14:12)

I understand the I need to load this on ionic v1.7,

my code:

```
     .factory("Tables", function ($firebaseArray, $rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.eventId = $window.localStorage.getItem('eventId');
    var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://....firebaseio.com/events/" + $rootScope.eventId + "/tables");
    return getAsArray(itemsRef);
  })
```

Is any way to load it with ionic way?

Comment: I think it problem of order of including js files.

Comment: I updated the question, see the order please

Comment: Can you include the code in which you call `getAsArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](https://github.com/katowulf/Firebase.getAsArray), you're missing the [Firebase.] part right?

it should be

> return Firebase.getAsArray(itemsRef);